Local Deployment Of Azure Functions Not Working When "azure-functions-maven-plugin" added to pom
I am new to Azure functions and am trying to deploy an azure function locally by following the guide https://quarkus.io/guides/azure-functions
The function is deployed successfully when run through
mvn quarkus:run

Now, I tried testing the azure maven plugin
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.36.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-functions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <appName>code-with-quarkus</appName>
                    <runtime>
                        <os>windows</os>
                        <javaVersion>17</javaVersion>
                    </runtime>
                    <appSettings>
                        <property>
                            <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
                            <value>~4</value>
                        </property>
                    </appSettings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

Now, On running the command
mvn azure-functions:run

the azure function is deployed successfully

but on hitting the endpoint, I don't get a response even though the function is triggered

I wanted to understand what the issue could be with the plugin and if I would need to set some properties explicitly to get it working. The entire pom file is added below
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>code-with-quarkus</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.13.0</compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>3.12.1</quarkus.platform.version>
        <skipITs>true</skipITs>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.2.5</surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-azure-functions</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.36.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-functions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <appName>code-with-quarkus</appName>
                    <runtime>
                        <os>windows</os>
                        <javaVersion>17</javaVersion>
                    </runtime>
                    <appSettings>
                        <property>
                            <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
                            <value>~4</value>
                        </property>
                    </appSettings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>



Check if below solution helps.

I have also faced the same issue when tried to run the Quarkus Azure function with the command mvn azure-functions:run. There is a GitHub issue in progress on the same issue.
I have created a quarkus Azure function using the command:
quarkus create app --extension=quarkus-azure-functions-http


As mentioned in the official Quarkus docs and MSDOC, mvn quarkus:dev (or) mvn quarkus:run should be used to run the quarkus function locally.

C:\Users\uname\quarkus-azure\functions-quarkus>mvn -DskipTests quarkus:dev      
                 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------< com.contoso:quarkus-azure-function >-----------------
[INFO] Building quarkus-azure-function 1.0.0
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus:2.13.0.Final:dev (default-cli) @ quarkus-azure-function ---
[INFO] Invoking org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources @ quarkus-azure-function
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Invoking org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile @ quarkus-azure-function   
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\uname\quarkus-azure\functions-quarkus\target\classes
[INFO] Invoking org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources @ quarkus-azure-function
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\uname\quarkus-azure\functions-quarkus\src\test\resources
[INFO] Invoking org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile @ quarkus-azure-function
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\uname\quarkus-azure\functions-quarkus\target\test-classes
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
__  ____  __  _____   ___  __ ____  ______ 
 --/ __ \/ / / / _ | / _ \/ //_/ / / / __/
 -/ /_/ / /_/ / __ |/ , _/ ,< / /_/ /\ \
--\___\_\____/_/ |_/_/|_/_/|_|\____/___/
2024-07-08 17:22:48,072 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) quarkus-azure-function 1.0.0 on JVM (powered by Quarkus 2.13.0.Final) started in 4.280s. Listening on: http://localhost:8080

2024-07-08 17:22:48,079 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Profile dev activated. Live Coding activated.                                                                                                  
2024-07-08 17:22:48,080 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Installed features: [cdi, funqy-http, smallrye-context-propagation, vertx]                                                                     
                                                                                                        
--                                                                                                      
Tests paused                                                                                            
Press [r] to resume testing, [o] Toggle test output, [:] for the terminal, [h] for more options>  

Response:


